# $digest already in progress in AngularJS custom directive inside UI Angular Tab

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

On costume directive which tries to build a morrischart inside angular ui bootstrap tabs I `getError: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`. The initial code looks as it follows.

here is a [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/aEd5FDvZwIGLj9UU0PcG/preview)

```
angular.module('ChartAngular', []).directive('linechart', function() {

        function createChart(el_id, options) {
          options.element = el_id;
          var r = new Morris.Line(options);
          return r;
        }

        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope:  {
            options: '='
          },
          replace: true,
          template: '<div></div>',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            return createChart(attrs.id, scope.options)
          }
        }
```

**Controller**

```
october.controllers['page/index'] = function ( $scope, $request) {


   $scope.chart_options = {
      data: [
        { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
        { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
        { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
        { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
      ],
      xkey: 'y',
      ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
      labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']  
    };

}
```

Than reading similar issues I was trying to use timeout on scope in my controller like

```
october.controllers['publishers/index'] = function ( $scope, $request, $timeout) {

$timeout(function(){
   $scope.chart_options = {
      data: [
        { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
        { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
        { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
        { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
      ],
      xkey: 'y',
      ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
      labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']  
    };

  }, 0);
}
```

but than directive option is not getting the data passed

```
I get Error: options is undefined
```

Still not enough experience with AngularJS so trying to figure out How to get this codes working.

this seems to work with one Chart per Tab

```
angular.module('ChartAngular', []).directive('linechart', function($timeout) {

    function createChart(el_id, options) {
      options.element = el_id;
      var r = new Morris.Line(options);
      return r;
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:  {
        options: '='
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<div></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("options", function() {
           if (scope.options) {                
                    $timeout(function() {
                        createChart(attrs.id, scope.options);
                    }, 3000)
                }
        });        
        //return createChart(attrs.id, scope.options)
      }
    }

  })
```

Comment: Are you sure the digest error comes from this directive?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that I'm trying to call the directive from angular ui bootstrap tab `<tab><linechart id="views" data-options="chart_options"></linechart><tab>` I found some workaround to load directive inside tab with 1 chart(see update) but with more than one charts per tab breaks again

Comment: Can you create a plunker/jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: yes I will prepare one